# PHP Mail - Restore apostrophes in content after using Filter Sanitize

Tags: php, forms, email, code-injection, sanitization

So I have Filter_Sanitize on a php form, which does a great job at making special characters "safe", but when outputted within a mail message it can look a little annoying. For example, instead of:

```
Hi I'm Jack and I'm going to Chloe's after dinner.
```

we get...

```
Hi I&#39;m Jack and I&#39;m going to Chloe&#39;s after dinner.
```

Is there a way to properly sanitize everything, and then add in apostrophes back so it looks normal when reading? Only thing I can think of is search and replace, searching for `"&#39;"` and replacing with `"'"`. But I feel like that wouldn't be the most seamless way to do it?

Some of the current code:

```
<?php
// Sanitize all data
$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$content = "
Name: $name
Email: $email
Message: $message
";

mail($send_to,$subject,$content,$headers);
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the flag `FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES` in order to avoid encoding quotes:

```
$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your answer. I'm still getting the same encoded output with apostrophes after using that code though. I'm going to investigate the filter flag though, that's totally new to me. Thanks!

Comment: Same here. FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES doesn't work